# How to calculate all possible values for $m$, where $m=i^k \mod p$, $k,p$ are fixed?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For example, all possible values for $i^{10} \mod 71$ is $1, 20, 30, 32, 37, 45, 48$. Is it possible to directly calculate these values without trying all possible $i$ from 1 to 71?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case $71-1=70$, so as the nonzero residues modulo $71$ form a cyclic
group of order $70$, the tenth powers form a cyclic group of order $7$.
So once you have one non-trivial value, say $10$, then $10^0$, $10^1$,
$10^2,\ldots,10^6$ are all of them.

Comment: for $i^{374}\mod 331$, the full answer is $1, 4, 16, 31, 64, 83, 124, 150, 165, 203, 256, 269, 299, 323, 329$. However, if we take $31$, $64$ to generate the list, only part of the answer can be obtained (of length 3 and 5, while the full answer has 15). Could you elaborate how to deal with this case? Thanks.

Comment: using the primitive root works, never mind.